# ¿Porque los controles en un WinForm no son visibles con el método Show()? Vb NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Tengo un problema amigos, estoy mandando a llamar un Winform, la instancia está correcta (New), y posterior a ello el método Show() no me enseña los controles que ya están creados desde el diseñador pero con el método ShowDialog() si, pero lo que ocupo es el otro método (Show()).

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si llamas a este método **InitializeComponent();**?

Comment: @Bicho no men, ni usando el constructor..

Comment: llamando al método debe funcionar.

Comment: @Bicho publique una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues he intentado infinidad de cosas, pero más que experimentar, quizá el entendimiento de algunas cosas que desconozco del lenguaje y el uso de las cosas, realicé diversas maneras y explico lo siguiente.

Si lo hago desde un mismo proyecto funciona correctamente lo mostrar todos los controles, componentes, etc en un Winform con el método Show() y ShowDialog()

El detalle es que yo estoy ejecutando este llamado desde una libreria (dll)

Y la única forma que me funcionó fue de la siguiente manera:

```
InstanciaFormulario.Show()
InstanciaFormulario.Update()
```

De esta forma el método Update obliga al diseñador de componentes a darle el 'foco' al control y sólo así me funciona, aunque creo que debería poderse de una manera más práctica.

Espero que le sirva a alguien.